# postman python code generation not adding configuration parameters

Tags: python, postman

I'm trying to generate python code from the postman, I'm able to generate code for it. But the code doesn't contain Configuration options.

FYI I'm using Auth2 python.

Please let me know if any option I'm missing.

[image]

Comment: configuration request is not part of the request. It is a feature in postman to help you create a token without you explicitly doing it . so it won't be there in the generated code as it has nothing to do with request in focus

Comment: If i want to implement in python, how shall I proceed?